# Notice: Undefined variable: tsk in C:\xampp\htdocs\online\Online Task Management System\task_mem.php on line 80

Tags: php

```
if($tsk != ""){
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM $tsk WHERE username = '$user'";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $acc = $db_field['accepted'];
    }


    if($acc == 1){
        die("<script>location.href = 'task_mem_acc.php'</script>");
    }
}
```

Notice: Undefined variable: tsk in C:\xampp\htdocs\online\Online Task Management System\task_mem.php on line 80

This problem always appear,

how to fix this problem?

please help me master!

Comment: $SQL = "SELECT * FROM ".$tsk." WHERE username = '$user'";

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Are you getting `tablename` dynamically each and everytime and your each table contains `username` field is that so..

Answer (score 0):

$tsk  is not defined . change your code to this.

```
if(isset($tsk) && $tsk != ""){
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM $tsk WHERE username = '$user'";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $acc = $db_field['accepted'];
    }


    if($acc == 1){
        die("<script>location.href = 'task_mem_acc.php'</script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Beside that there are tons of dupe's for this question, this line: `if(isset($tsk) && $tsk != ""){` is the same as: `if(!empty($tsk))`

Comment: I had declare $tsk. This is my coding.                                                     if (isset($led_nem)) {
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE username = '$led_nem'";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $tsk = $db_field['group_task'];
}
}